# lirc irw and runaway keypress

Tags: lirc

Total noob here. My college senior project team is building a robot that runs off Raspberry Pi. We're using an IR remote to control its movements. I've been learning to use the Pi as I go, and I've been struggling. Took me three days to finally get `irw` to register keypresses from the remote. Irrecord was recording two sets of code like this:

```
KEY_1                            0x00FF6897 0x7E867B4C
Key_2                            0x00FF9867 0x7E867B4C
```

and so on. Finally figured out from extensive google fu that the second code (`0x7E867B4C` in this case) was preventing `irw` from registering keypresses, and that deleting that portion from each key made it work. The problem I'm having now is this: when I press keys, sometimes (not always) the key press will start running away. It starts entering the lowercase letter or symbol associated with they key name of the button I pressed, so if I press `KEY_A`, it will read on the screen as:

```
0000000000f700ff 00 KEY_A ROBOT2
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This continues until I hit enter on the keyboard. What is causing this, and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: my google fu is weak.  I could easily wiki lirc, but no luck irw.  Can you give me link for irw.  I also found some guy using irman.  But again no clue searching AliExpres for irman.  Is it some sort of gaming keypad?

Comment: I googled harder and found more useful posts - LIRC no output from irw
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37579/lirc-no-output-from-irw

What do I need to control multiple linear servos to push buttons from a raspberry pi? [closed]
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98674/what-do-i-need-to-control-multiple-linear-servos-to-push-buttons-from-a-raspberr/98683#98683