# lirc infrared receiver: no `irw` output (`irrecord` works!)

Tags: raspbian-buster, lirc

The question is similar to [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37579/lirc-no-output-from-irw) asked 5 years ago. But the provided answer won't solve my issue.

**Problem**: `irw` won't show anything although prior configuratin via `irrecord` was successful.

## Setup

- Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
- Buster 10.6 raspberrypi 5.4.72-v7+
- lircd 0.10.1
- Receiver GPIO 17

## Configuration

### `/boot/config`

```
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
```

### `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf`

```
[lircd]
nodaemon        = False
driver          = default
device          = /dev/lirc0
output          = /var/run/lirc/lircd
pidfile         = /var/run/lirc/lircd.pid
plugindir       = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lirc/plugins
permission      = 666
allow-simulate  = No
repeat-max      = 600

[lircmd]
uinput          = False
nodaemon        = False
```

### `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf`

```
include "lircd.conf.d/*.conf"
```

### `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/elegoo.lircd.conf`

This file was created with `irrecord`: `sudo irrecord -n -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd.conf`

```
begin remote

  name  elegoo
  driver devinput
  bits           56
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  one             0     0
  zero            0     0
  pre_data_bits   8
  pre_data       0x23
  gap          99861
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0
  frequency    38000

      begin codes
          KEY_POWER                0x49010000001181
          # ...
          KEY_9                    0x44010000001187
      end codes

end remote
```

### Testing

```
sudo mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc0
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc0
Trying device: /dev/lirc0
Using device: /dev/lirc0
Running as regular user pi
pulse 9053
space 4459
...
space 2212
pulse 607
timeout 125069
```

### Logging

Starting the service with `sudo systemctl start lircd`

```
Info: lircd:  Opening log, level: Info
Notice: Version: lircd 0.10.1
Notice: System info: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.72-v7+ #1356 SMP Thu Oct 22 13:56:54 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
Info: Initial device: /dev/lirc0
Info: [lirc] protocol is enabled
Info: Initial device: /dev/lirc0
Info: [lirc] protocol is enabled
Notice: Options: driver: default
Notice: Options: output: /var/run/lirc/lircd
Notice: Options: nodaemon: 1
Notice: Options: plugindir: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lirc/plugins
Notice: Options: logfile: syslog
Notice: Options: immediate-init: 0
Notice: Options: permission: 666
Notice: Options: driver-options:
Notice: Options: pidfile: /var/run/lirc/lircd.pid
Notice: Options: listen: 0
Notice: Options: connect: (null)
Notice: Options: userelease: 0
Notice: Options: effective_user: (null)
Notice: Options: release_suffix: _EVUP
Notice: Options: allow_simulate: 0
Notice: Options: repeat_max: 600
Notice: Options: configfile: /etc/lirc/lircd.conf
Notice: Options: dynamic_codes: (null)
Notice: Current driver: default
Notice: Driver API version: 3
Notice: Driver  version: 0.10.0
Notice: Driver  info: See file:///usr/share/doc/lirc/plugindocs/default.html
Info: lircd:  Opening log, level: Info
Warning: Running as root
Info: Using remote: elegoo.
Notice: lircd(default) ready, using /var/run/lirc/lircd
```

Starting `irw`:

```
Notice: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
Info: [lirc] protocol is enabled
```

As you can see I get no warnings or whatsoever. It must be something simple. Please can anybody advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

had the same problem, mode2 testing fine, irw nothing.

the problem:
irrecord adds more hex code than necessary, the second hex-row causes errors without any error message

KEY_CHANNELDOWN       0x00FFA25D   0x00000001

after deleting the second row, irw works fine:

KEY_CHANNELDOWN       0x00FFA25D

try deleting

KEY_POWER                0x49010000001181

to

KEY_POWER                0x49010000

Comment: In the meantime I switched to `ir-keytable` but you are right, removing the obsolete dword solved the problem!